# Rendering to texture: RGB blending is ok, but A works strange

Tags: opengl, shader

I am on OpenGL 4.3.

When I need "normal" blending, I usually use `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`.
RGB channels are blended fine, but alpha is not. I want it to be:

```
A = dstA + srcA * (1 - dstA)
// Or `A = srcA + dstA * (1 - srcA)`, result is the same.
```

(It's how blending in Paint.NET and some other editors works.)
But looks like it is

```
A = srcA * srcA + dstA * (1 - srcA)
// Or `A = srcA`, I'm not sure.
```

Can I somehow achieve the desired result? Maybe, different blending func or modifying color values in shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE);`

This has the equation `(sC*sA) + (dC*(1-sA))` ("standard" blending) for the RGB channels, but `(sA*(1-dA)) + (dA*1)` for the alpha channel, which matches the equation you want.

Note that `glBlendFuncSeparate` is an extension function added in OpenGL 1.4. While every modern PC should support it, you won't be able to access it directly from the library.

http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php is a good tool for visualizing different combinations to `glBlendFunc[Separate]`.